# Download only apt-get without installing

Tags: apt, 20.04

I know I can run `sudo apt install gnome-tweak-tool` and it will prompt me to enter sudo pass and then proceed to download and install gnome tweak tools. But what if I want to only download and not install it?

I know I can then do `sudo apt install gnome-tweak-tool -d`

I have however already installed it, and when running this command I get:

```
sudo apt install gnome-tweak-tool -d -f
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
gnome-tweak-tool is already the newest version (3.34.0-2ubuntu1).
0 to upgrade, 0 to newly install, 0 to remove and 78 not to upgrade.
```

How do I download it, and keep a local copy? I want a local copy, because I am going to a place without internet and I have another laptop with me, where I want to install the some packages, but I wont be able to unless I have a local repository copy of them.

Comment: What worked was: sudo apt-get download gnome-tweak-tool and this got downloaded to the local folder

Comment: I can however not download any package and its dependencies as long as the package is already latest version. There seems to be now way to work around the apt-get command to download only and not also install or have it check for already installed packages.

Answer (score 1):

You could execute

```
sudo apt install --download-only gnome-tweak-tool
```

This will download gnome-tweak-tool with any dependencies you need and place them in /var/cache/apt/archives. Later a subsequent `apt-get install gnome-tweak-tool` will be able to complete without any extra downloads.

Comment: This produces the same result. Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
gnome-tweak-tool is already the newest version (3.34.0-2ubuntu1).
0 to upgrade, 0 to newly install, 0 to remove and 78 not to upgrade.

Comment: i kinda wish we could configure apt to not need sudo in this case

Comment: why's that? If we don't use sudo when installing, then we got all these open doors Windows has. I do not agree...